# How to customize antd theme on runtime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, customization, antd

I have been working with antd for quite sometime now. So far in my react app I have customized antd theme in webpack configuration and have updated default less variables.

Or If Im using create react app, in that case I customized the theme by modifyling variables in `config-overrides.js`.

But Now I have a feature in my app to have multiple themes and the user could choose the theme of the application on runtime i-e on clicking a button I want to change the theme of the entire application. How is this possible with antd since in its case all the customization is done in the build configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the documentation [link](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) I have gone through. But it doesn't provide anything for my usecase.

Comment: What about creating a _HOC_, as a theme provider, which chooses from user choice to return the regular App which is themed via _AntD_, or, in the case of user selection for _MaterialUI_ theme, the HOC would `return` the _MuiTheme_ provider to wrap the whole app with?

Comment: @SultanH. I have updated my question please don't mix it with material-ui.

Comment: With antd even with the HOC, the theme wont be changed since the customization is done in the webpack configuration for making the build. And this configuration is actually modifying antd less variables.

Comment: But, wouldn't that affect only AntD components?

Comment: Yeah but considering my use case I don't want to choose between material ui theme and antd theme. I edited that in the question. Basically I want to choose between antd themes so that the app supports more than one antd theme. So the application is built with just antd and now I want to have multiple themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ npm install --save antd-theme
```

app.jsx

```
import { Button, Select } from 'antd';
import { ThemeProvider, useTheme } from 'antd-theme';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';

const initialTheme = {
  name: 'default',
  variables: { 'primary-color': '#00ff00' },
};

const ThemeSelect = () => {
  const [{ name, variables, themes }, setTheme] = useTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        style={{ width: 100 }}
        value={name}
        onChange={
          (theme) => setTheme({ name: theme, variables })
        }
      >
        {
          themes.map(
            ({ name }) => (
              <Select.Option key={name} value={name}>
                {name}
              </Select.Option>
            )
          )
        }
      </Select>
      <SketchPicker
        color={variables['primary-color']}
        onChange={(value) => {
          // Will update all css attributes affected by primary-color
          setTheme({ name, variables: { 'primary-color': value.hex } });
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(initialTheme);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider
      theme={theme}
      onChange={(value) => setTheme(value)}
    >
      <ThemeSelect />
      <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

config-overrides.js

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader, addPostcssPlugins, adjustStyleLoaders, addWebpackPlugin } = require('customize-cra');

const AntdThemePlugin = require('antd-theme/plugin');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  }),
  adjustStyleLoaders(
    (loaders) => {
      loaders.use[0] = {
        loader: AntdThemePlugin.loader
      }
    }
  ),
  addWebpackPlugin(
    new AntdThemePlugin({
      variables: ['primary-color'],
      themes: [
        {
          name: 'dark',
          filename: require.resolve('antd/lib/style/themes/dark.less'),
        },
        {
          name: 'compact',
          filename: require.resolve('antd/lib/style/themes/compact.less'),
        },
      ],
    })
  ),
);
```